# Currency Converter BindingsでamountInOtherCurrencyをbindすると、ブランクウインドウが表示される

Tags: swift, macos

Currency Converter Bindingsを[vivacocoaのテキスト](http://vivacocoa.jp/swift/swift29.html)に従って作っています。StoryBoard上で3つあるテキストフィールドのうち、3番目をbindすると、ブランクウインドウが表示され、3つのbindすべてを解除するとビューは正しく表示されます。その後、1番目、2番目とバインドしても平気で、やはり3番目をバインドするとブランクに戻ります。

3番目をバインドすると、Xcodeのログには、次のメッセージが出ます。

1.デフォルトの状態

```
2020-05-04 14:57:55.235244+0900 Currency Converter Bindings[33248:1667757] Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): [<Currency_Converter_Bindings.Converter 0x6000002549c0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key amountInOtherCurrency.
```

2.スキームの引数に-NSBindingDebugLogLevel 1をセットした場合

```
2020-05-04 13:43:07.679365+0900 Currency Converter Bindings[32504:1618056] Cocoa Bindings: Error accessing value for key path selection.amountInOtherCurrency of object <NSObjectController: 0x600003304aa0>[object class: NSMutableDictionary] (from bound object <NSTextField: 0x1004118e0>): [<Currency_Converter_Bindings.Converter 0x60000020a160> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key amountInOtherCurrency.
```

モデルとなるConverterクラスのコード

```
import Cocoa

class Converter: NSObject {

    @objc dynamic var exchangeRate:Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var dollarsToConvert:Double = 0.0

    func amountInOtherCurrency() ->Double {
        return self.exchangeRate * self.dollarsToConvert
    }

    override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String> {
        if key == "amountInOtherCurrency" {
            return Set<String>(arrayLiteral: "exchangeRate", "dollarsToConvert")
        } else {
            return super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

体系的な理解ができていないため、色々いじりましたが、何故うまく動作しないのか分かりません。どうか皆さんのお知恵をお貸しください。ちなみに同じUIパーツでObjecctive-Cで作ったものは動きました。

Comment: 随分古い記事を参考にしているようですね。とりあえずログを本文中に入れる場合には、コードと同様に整形してやらないと一部の情報がうまく表示されませんので、今後質問を編集されたり、別質問を書かれる場合には気を付けてみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOSのBindingの仕組みはObjective-Cの動的な機構に基づいているため、若干のObjective-Cに関する知識が必要です。

残念ながら、リンク先の記事の時代とはObjective-C関連の動作が変わってしまったので、もし古い記事を参考にするのであれば、そこら辺は自分で調べて修正してやらないといけません。

で、BindingのModel Key Pathに`amountInOtherCurrency`と入力するのであれば、Objective-C側から`amountInOtherCurrency`と言うメソッドが見えていないといけません。

記事に書いてあるコードに対して、2つのプロパティと同じように、Swiftの`amountInOtherCurrency()`メソッドにも`@objc`をつけてやらないとObjective-C側からは見えません。

```
    @objc func amountInOtherCurrency() -> Double {
        return exchangeRate * dollarsToConvert
    }
```

(Model→Viewへの一方向Bindingでは、dynamicはなくても動くんですが、つけても構いません。)

あるいは、他の2つに合わせるなら、計算型プロパティに変更しても構いません。

```
    @objc var amountInOtherCurrency: Double {
        exchangeRate * dollarsToConvert
    }
```

---

エラーメッセージにある、「this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key amountInOtherCurrency」と言うのは、「`amountInOtherCurrency`と言うキーについて、KVCに準拠していない」と言う意味ですが、言い換えると「`amountInOtherCurrency`に対応するgetter(場合によってはsetter)メソッドが存在しないか、Objective-C側から見えない」と言うことになります。

メッセージの意味を理解して正しく対応できるようにしてください。

Comment: おっしゃる通りでした。@objcの追加で動きました。まだまだ勉強が足りないようです。これから勉強していきます。ありがとうございました。